# Why can't Swift recognize the array sent by JS?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, networking

I am communicating with `js` using `Webview`. I transfer into parameter api the received data again. But when `Swift` get an array from `JS`, `Swift` don't recognize it properly.

**Where to Send Data from JS**

```js
var jsonData = {
  data,
  type : "fromjs"
};
alert(jsonData)
webkit.messageHandlers.sendFromJS.postMessage(jsonData);
```

**Data Viewed by Alerts**

```
{
    "type" = "fromjs",
    "data" = {
            "num": "one",
            "arr_data" : [{ "title": "test1", "val" : "testval1" },
                          { "title": "test2" , "val" : "testval2"}]
           }
}
```

**I check the data received by Swift.**

```swift
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
   if message.name == "sendFromJS" {
        let getdata = message.body as! NSDictionary
        print(getdata)
```

**But Swift doesn't recognize the array properly.**

```
{
    type = "fromjs",
    data = {
            "num": "one",
            "arr_data" : ({ "title": "test1", "val" : "testval1" },
                          { "title": "test2" , "val" : "testval2"})
           }
}
```

`Swift` recognizes square brackets as parentheses.

How can you solve this problem? I have to send the data that I received by putting it in the parameters as it is.

```swift
func apiCall(_ param: NSDictionary){
   let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = param["data"] as! [String : AnyObject]
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
```

I've changed the type of data. But it's equally unrecognizable.

```swift
let getdata = message.body as! [String : Any]
 print(getdata)

//log
[
    type = "fromjs",
    data = {
            "num": "one",
            "arr_data" : ({ "title": "test1", "val" : "testval1" },
                          { "title": "test2" , "val" : "testval2"})
           }
]
```

**To create json data in js**

```js
var data = {
  num: "one"
};
var data_arr = [];
data_arr.push({"title": "test1", "val" : "testval1"});
data_arr.push({"title": "test2" , "val" : "testval2"});
data.arr_data = data_arr;
var jsonData = {
  data,
  type : "fromjs"
};
alert(jsonData)
webkit.messageHandlers.sendFromJS.postMessage(jsonData);
```

Comment: @FahriAzimov  I wrote down the data shown in the Swift log in the question. Is this correct? So why doesn't the parameters have an array?

Comment: Yes, it's correct, because you are printing the `NSDictionary`, if you print Swift dictionary, it will have square brackets )

Comment: Sorry, my prev. comment was a little wrong, deleted it

Comment: Anyways, don't use Objective C types with Swift, it has it's own types, for the dictionary, it has `Dictionary`, or you can directly use `[String: Any]` as type and it will be a dictionary.

Comment: @FahriAzimov Do you mean to change the parameter type of the function to [String: Any]?

Comment: @FahriAzimov  Please look at the question that I modified.

Comment: How do you create the `data`? I think, that has some problem.

Comment: @FahriAzimov Please look at the question that I modified.

Comment: It should have a comma between `"num": "one"` and `"arr_data"`. I don't know why, but it does not have that. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: @FahriAzimov I'm sorry. I forgot by mistake.

Comment: @FahriAzimov But it's a mistake in the question, not in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a difference in the way that `JSON` and traditional NeXT property lists represent arrays.

**Example**

```swift
let json = """{ "a": [1, 2, 3] }"""
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(json.utf8), options: [])
print("plist:", jsonData)
let jsonString = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: d, options: [.prettyPrinted])
print("json:", String(data: jsonString, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

**Print Log**

```
plist: {
    a =     (
        1,
        2,
        3
    );
}
json: {
  "a" : [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

The property list renders the array using ( … ) but that’s just a rendering oddity.  The actual objects are correct, as witnessed by the fact that I can turn them back into the some JSON I started with.